# Create new ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT for Development

Tags: c#, json, windows, asp.net-core, development-environment

I need a second `Development` environment that I call `DevelopmentExt` so I created this section in my `launchSettings.json`:

```json
"CoolApp.DevelopmentExt": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": false,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "DevelopmentExt"
  },
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/"
},
```

In order to use different settings for this configuration I use this extension:

```cs
public static class HostingEnvironmentExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDevelopmentExt(this IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        return hostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment("DevelopmentExt");
    }
}
```

This, however, gives me only general error pages and the browser says:

> Swapping to **Development** environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

I guess this indicates that my `DevelopmentExt` is not a *real* `Development`. Is there a way that I can setup it to be recognized as such?

Comment: Show your `Startup.cs`

Comment: You might be able to configure the developer exception page middleware to show detailed errors in that env as well

Comment: @juunas this is it! I had the default condition `if (env.IsDevelopment())` and changed it to `if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsDevelopmentExt())` so now I can see the full error page! Cool, thanks! I totaly forgot that this is done by a middlewere and was looking in the wrong place ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you'll need to change the condition to include the developer exception page middleware to:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsDevelopmentExt())
```

With it included, you should see detailed exceptions.